# Firebase. как отключить проект от бд? android studio

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase, app

На создавал миллион БД в firebase. Потом вспомнил что бесплатно может работать только одна. Удалили все, а в проекте все равно висит "conected". Как подключиться к новой БД по новой?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все довольно просто.
Заходите в проводник файлов, в папку, где хранятся другие папки с названиями файлов всех ваших проектов в Android Studio, открываете папку нужно проекта.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем открываете папку "app" (она создается во всех проектах андроид студио, но может называться по другому, если вы ее переименовывали. p.s.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]это самая корневая папка проекта).

И удаляете файл "google-services.json".
Затем открываете свой проект с андроид студио, нажимаете кнопку "Sync Project with Gradle Files".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом все, галочка в разделе "1) Connect your app to Firebase" исчезла.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хорошего дня:)